# Recommended way to manage many different destinations / stages?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

What is the recommended way of managing multiple release stages / destinations?

We currently use a combination of stages to release to a staging or production environment for any customer, but this means that we have (customer x 2 environments) = 20 stages right now and the overview page is getting unwieldy fast.

[image]

I agree that we should strive to keep as many customers as possible on the same version, but this is not always possible nor wanted.

Is there a better way to manage all these stages?

Answer (score 0):

In your situation,one idea I can think of is trying to use deployment groups to put ten customers' machines into one deployment group, a deployment group is a logical set of deployment target machines that have agents installed on each one. Deployment groups represent the physical environments. So that only two deployment groups are needed for two environments, which should be more convenient.But the trouble with this is that you need to have an agent for each machine.For details on how to operate, you can refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops).

Comment: Doesn't this mean that all customers in the same deployment group would get the same version, all in 1 deploy? That is something we have to avoid because not every customer approves at the same time. Since we're releasing IIS websites we only deploy to 2 separate machines. We are already using deployment groups to separate the web servers from the processing and database servers.

Comment: If so, there may be no better management way, see if other contributors have good ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You may do it with [Multi-configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#multi-configuration). Then the result would be a stage of a customer.